# Accessibility PDF viewer

Tags: pdf, accessibility

I have been using Ubuntu for a longtime. But i am not fully working in Ubuntu. so my knowledge is very limited. sorry for anything i am wrong.

Nowadays customers are asking to provide Accessibility PDF (means pdf with Tagged PDF, XMP metadata, etc). I have look around various pdf libraries in linux. But i am not able to find something like "Tags" left panel in the Adobe Professional.

is there any pdf software available for linux?

regards,
Srikrishnan